# Complex logic binary and M

Tags: logic, optimization, linear-programming, constraints, binary-programming

Here's the problem:

a and b are continuous between -15 and 15. Explain how the following conditions can be represented as linear constraints using binary variables: At least two of the conditions must be met.

Condition 1:
$(a-b)^2 \le 16$

Condition 2:
$ b \le 3$ and $a \ge -1$

Condition 3:
$a = -1 $

Note that big-M parameters must be the best possible big Ms.

I think there should be a binary variable for each condition, and that condition 2 must be split out into two binary variables, but I feel pretty lost on how I can apply big M logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you want three binary variables $x_i$, with linear constraint $\sum_i x_i \ge 2$.  Note that the first condition is equivalent to $|a-b|\le 4$. The big-M constraints are
\begin{align}
a-b-4&\le M_1(1-x_1)\\
-a+b-4&\le M_2(1-x_1)\\
b-3&\le M_3(1-x_2)\\
-a-1 &\le M_4(1-x_2)\\
-a-1 &\le M_5(1-x_3)\\
a+1 &\le M_6(1-x_3)\\
\end{align}
I’ll leave it you to supply the big-M values.

Comment: Ahh thank you! I can do the rest.